# php pear net_dns

Tags: php, dns, pear

HI

Does anyone know where I can find good documentation on the Pear module Net_DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is its [End-User Documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-dns.php), on PEAR's website.

There are a couple of examples for some methods, like [`Net_DNS_Resolver::query()`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-dns.net-dns-resolver.query.php).

*(Yeah, one problem with PEAR package is that some of them are not that well documented... This doesn't seem to bad, on this point ; I've seen worse ^^ )*

Answer (score 0):

there is also the generated API docs for Net_DNS; available at http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS/docs/latest/

If you have the time, and feel like you would like to help the PEAR project, you could always submit an update or "Documentation Problem" bug report.